# FAILED: Test.Registration.doRegis java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.click()" because "this.terms" is null

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using nestng and all the elements are interacting properly but getting issue in one class .

This is my cart class

```
package POM;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class Cart {
    @FindBy(xpath = "//select[@name='CountryId']")
    private WebElement coi;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//option[text()='India']")
    private WebElement india;
    
    @FindBy(xpath= "//*[@id='termsofservice']")
    WebElement terms;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='checkout']")
    WebElement buttonCheckout;
    
    
    public void selectCountryId() {
        coi.click();
    }
    
    public void selectCountry() {
        india.click();
    }
    
    public void checkTerms() {
        terms.click();
    }
    
    public void clickCheckout() {
        buttonCheckout.click();
    }
    
}
```

And this is my class for running it , test !

```
package Test;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import POM.AddToCartPage;
import POM.BillingPage;
import POM.Cart;
import POM.PaymentInfo;
import POM.RegistrationPages;
import Utils.DriverUtils;

public class Registration {
    @Test
    
    public void doRegis() throws InterruptedException {
        DriverUtils.getDriver().get("https://demowebshop.tricentis.com/register");
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        RegistrationPages r = new RegistrationPages();
        
        r.selGenderClick();
        r.enterFirstName("SomeName");
        r.enterLastName("SomeLastNAme");
        r.enterEmail("Someto34w0dfd00hgt22@ymail.com");
        r.enterPassword("Something@123");
        r.confirmPassword("Something@123");
        r.clickRegister();
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        r.clickContinue();
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        AddToCartPage addtocart = new AddToCartPage();
        
        addtocart.clickAddTOCart();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        addtocart.clickGotoCart();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        Cart c = new Cart();
        
        c.selectCountryId();
        c.selectCountry();
        c.checkTerms();
        c.clickCheckout();
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        BillingPage bp = new BillingPage();
        
        bp.selectCountry();
        bp.enterCity("Spme City");
        bp.enterAdd1("Somwwhere");
        bp.enterPostalCode("465629");
        bp.enterPhone("54546561");
        bp.clickcontinue();
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        bp.againContinue();
        
        
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        bp.againClickContinue();
        
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        bp.selectPaymentMethod();
        
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        bp.againContinue();
        
        PaymentInfo pi = new PaymentInfo();
        
        pi.enterName("Some Name");
        pi.enterCard("54696187987");
        pi.clickContinue();
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Now this add to cart class is working fine , I am not getting any error , also i have checked the xpath , it is also finding the element , but then also i am getting null pointer error.
I am also sharing this add to cart class :

```
package POM;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class AddToCartPage extends BasePage {
    @FindBy(xpath= "/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/input")
    WebElement addToCart;
    
    @FindBy(xpath= "//span[contains(text(),'Shopping cart')]")
    WebElement goToCart;
    
    public void clickAddTOCart() {
        addToCart.click();
    }
    
    public void clickGotoCart() {
        goToCart.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: ```@FindBy(xpath= "//*[@id='termsofservice']") WebElement terms;```. post this element's html code

Comment: i used this is on the website : https://demowebshop.tricentis.com/

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius <input id="termsofservice" type="checkbox" name="termsofservice">